# Create account through google analytics v4 admin API

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-4

I need to create g4 analytics accounts at scale.

I made a call to the API according to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1alpha/accounts/provisionAccountTicket):

```
apiClient.request({
      method: "POST",
      url: "https://analyticsadmin.googleapis.com/v1alpha/accounts:provisionAccountTicket",
      data: {
        account: {
          displayName: "Test Account",
          regionCode: "US",
        },
        redirectUri: "https://my-redirect-url",
      },
    }),
```

And I got this response:

```
{ accountTicketId: "4iR-Ogm8RDSMoV3lQpjZjQ" }
```

How do I proceed here?
What's the next step?

Answer (score 2):

As per [account provsioning.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1#account_provisioning)

> This method returns the accountTicketId field that should be included in the Terms of Service (TOS) URL: `https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/?provisioningSignup=false#/termsofservice/ACCOUNT_TICKET_ID`. Once a user visits the TOS URL and accepts the Terms of Service, creation of a Google Analytics account will be complete (Account provisioning sample).

So the next step would be to have the user visit the page listed and approve the TOS.

Comment: how do I create that page? isn't that something hosted on google?

Comment: Yes it hosted by google you just have to navigate to it in a web browser.    replace the ACCOUNT_TICKET_ID with the one you got back and open it in a web browser.

Comment: oh I see. The thing is we are managing 10k+ businesses, so we need to open them accounts in a scalable way. How do we do that?

Comment: You don't. The owner of the account needs to approve the TOS.  This is not something you should be doing for them.  You can't agree to a TOS on behalf of another company.

Answer (score 0):

As per previous comment and as it is mentioned in the Google's api [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1beta/accounts/provisionAccountTicket)

```
request = {
          account,
          redirectUri
          };
          const newAc = await analyticsAdminClient.provisionAccountTicket(request);
          console.log(`https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/?provisioningSignup=false#/termsofservice/${newAc[0].accountTicketId}`);
```

Console statement from above url will take you to Google's TOC page, just accept the T&C and you are done. Account will be created.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally there would be a way to do this with a service account but that's not possible do to security I think. You would need to have the user creating the request to accept TOS by going to 'https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/?provisioningSignup=false#/termsofservice/TICKETNUMBER'. I'm actually working on something similar at scale for GTM and GA4 so this is one of the many problems I'm facing.

Also see ref code from git: https://github.com/googleapis/python-analytics-admin/blob/main/samples/accounts_provision_account_ticket.py